# How is the Node.js v8.x binary distribution for Linux built?

Tags: node.js, linux

I'm working with Node.js 8.9.4, the current LTS version.

If I download the 64 bit Linux binary distribution of that version from the Node.js website (https://nodejs.org/dist/v8.9.4/node-v8.9.4-linux-x64.tar.xz), then the **node** executable it includes will run on Red Hat Enterprise Linux 6. (I need to be able to target this version of RHEL).

I have also built Node v8.9.4 from source, following the instructions at https://github.com/nodejs/node/blob/master/BUILDING.md#building-nodejs-on-supported-platforms. Doing this required gcc 4.9.4 or newer, as per that page, because C++11 support is now required.

However, the node binary that results from that build will not run on RHEL 6, because the standard C++ library (libstdc++.so) that ships with RHEL 6 is from GCC 4.4.7. It's necessary to reference the libgcc and libstdc++ from the newer version of GCC that was used to build node to get it to work.

I *think* this means that the Linux binary distributions on the Node.js website are not built using the process described in the build instructions - if they were, they would not run on RHEL 6.

Is there any information on how the binary distributions of Node.js are built? Are there some options to the configure script that I'm missing?

(The reason for this question: I'm trying to build a Node C++ add-on, which needs to target RHEL 6, and hitting the same problem with the version of gcc required to build it vs. the version of the GCC/C++ runtime on RHEL 6. Yes, I could distribute the runtime libraries with my application, but there is obviously a better solution, because the binary distribution of Node is using it).

Comment: An executable created on RHEL6 with a later gcc : Assume a gcc with internal `libgcc_s.so.1 , libstdc++.so.6 -> libstdc++.so.6.0.20` (gcc-4.9.3 example). The executable can be started with a script that sets the `LD_LIBRARY_PATH` to a non PATH directory with the new { libstdc++.so.6, libgcc_s.so.1 }.